# Different voltage drops depending on the path

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage

I was working through a problem in electromagnetic induction when I discovered that I have a fundamental ignorance of some sort that is puzzling me.

Consider a circular wire, at rest, perpendicular to an homogeneous magnetic field that may vary its intensity with time. The wire has constant resistance per unit of length. After marking two points on the wire defining a quarter of a circle I call them $N$ and $E$. Now I join them with a straight piece of the same wire to get the following configuration:

$\hskip1.65in$[image]

I know that I can use Faraday's law to get the induced EMF $\mathcal{E}$ via $\mathcal{E} = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$ in each of the circuits. I'm also aware of the conservation intuition behind Faraday's law: the induced current will be such that it will generate a magnetic field that cancels the variation of the magnetic field. I thought that the current through the straight wire should be zero because of this intuition and the fact that the straight wire is part of both circuits. I checked that intuition quatitatively after applying twice the Faraday's law and  once the Kirchhoff's law for the node $N$.

My "problem" now is that the voltage drop form $E$ to $N$ can have three different values:

- $\Delta\neq 0$ if I follow the upper arc
- $3 \cdot \Delta$ if I follow the lower arc
- $0$ if I follow the straight wire

Why is that the case? I think that this might has something to do with the fact that this is an induced EMF and not one generated by a regular battery or something like that, but I'm not sure.

Also, is this some kind general phenomenon? I mean, if you have a flat, outer circuit with any shape and then you add in some bridges and perform the same experiment, will the current through those inner wires be zero?

Comment: Kirchoff's voltage law (the law that tells us to expect the voltage drop to be the same for any two paths between two points) is not valid in the presence of fluctuating magnetic fields.

Comment: @ThePhoton: It's not that Kirchhoff's laws are not valid, they just don't tell you anything about the problem, they are concerned with lumped element approximation, while this is a field problem. Kirchhoff's laws don't work between "points" in space, they work between _nodes_ of a circuit. The above scenario can be modeled nicely for quasi-static fields using a nodal approximation, the induced voltages/currents simply have to be included explicitly as sources.

Comment: What you have here is not a circuit but an electromagnetic field problem. You were told how to calculate induced voltages. Use that knowledge.

Comment: Start 5 minutes into this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUUMCT7FjaI

Answer (score -1):

Resistive systems are not conservative.  This can be seen by the fact that the system experiences a potential drop whichever direction current passes through a resistor.  The current is essentially experiencing a drag force which cannot be written as the gradient of a potential function; you can't 'draw' the potential landscape for a resistor, so it won't have the path independent property you have in mind.

Comment: But why that explanation does not work for a regular circuit with batteries and resistors? For those cases you use the fact that voltage drops in circuits are always zero to get equations but that is equivalent to say that the voltage drop does not depend on the path.

Comment: @Picito: Circuits don't have paths, they have nodes and nets. The necessary physical approximation that makes a physical jumble of parts and real wires made out of metal into a circuit is that the potential on all wires is almost constant and that the electromagnetic fields are completely restricted to the vicinity of the wires. You can extend that simplification to the quasi-static field case where fields can be stuffed into sources, but beyond that the nodal approximation breaks down completely and you need to solve Maxwell's equations.